# global variable section php

Tags: php, global-variables

Ok, but I don't want to use post and get.

Is there a way to set a global variable to be visible in any page I want???

Like a variable in the user section?

Or should I pass the variable just with post get?

If so, is there a way to pass a hidden variable with post without puting it on a form?

Comment: Is this global variable to be shared across all users, or only one particular user?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a variable that stay between all your pages, you can use a superglobal variable, but it is not best practice and it will be deprecated in PHP 6.

You should use sessions to keep variable through every pages.

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['var_name'] = "data";
?>
```

Then, you should be able to access `$_SESSION['var_name']` everywhere until the destruction of the session (when the function `session_destruct()` will be executed).

You have to use `session_start()` at the beginning of the files where you will want to use the session variables.

But remember that the data stored can be different for each user (every different sessions).

Comment: just as a reminder, this will only work as global variables for a particular user.  once you go to another user, that variable will not be shared.  you will need to either store that variable in a database or another file in order to make it truly global (across all users).  but, i'm not sure what scope you are looking for here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) and or [set cookies](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php).